# Sanitize and send checkbox results in a form

Tags: php, html, email, checkbox, html-email

I have a WordPress based website that includes a booking `<form>` on a 'Page Template'.

As I am unfamiliar with PHP, I'm not too sure exactly where I am going wrong.

I need to include some `checkboxes` for the services offered by the website in a `<form>` and have the following file to work with:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Booking Page
 */
?>

<?php
    // Sanitize data, or initialize if they don't exist.
    $clientname = isset($_POST['ci_name']) ? esc_html(trim($_POST['ci_name'])) : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['ci_email']) ? esc_html(trim($_POST['ci_email'])) : '';
            $services = isset($_POST['services']) ? esc_html(trim(implode(",", $_POST['services']))) : ''; // My Edit
    $message = isset($_POST['ci_comments']) ? sanitize_text_field(stripslashes($_POST['ci_comments'])) : '';

    $errorString = '';
    $emailSent = false;

    if(isset($_POST['send_booking']))
    {
        // We are here because the form was submitted. Let's validate!

        if(empty($clientname) or mb_strlen($clientname) < 2)
            $errorString .= '<li><i class="fa fa-times"></i> '.__('Your name is required.', 'ci_theme').'</li>';

        if(empty($email) or !is_email($email))
            $errorString .= '<li><i class="fa fa-times"></i> '.__('A valid email is required.', 'ci_theme').'</li>';

                // Services is optional, so, no check.  // My Edit
        // Message is optional, so, no check.    

        // Alright, lets send the email already!
        if(empty($errorString))
        {
            $mailbody  = __("Name:", 'ci_theme') . " " . $clientname . "\n";
            $mailbody .= __("Email:", 'ci_theme') . " " . $email . "\n";
                    $mailbody .= __("Services Selected:", 'ci_theme') . " " . $services . "\n"; // My Edit
            $mailbody .= __("Message:", 'ci_theme') . " " . $message . "\n";

            // If you want to receive the email using the address of the sender, comment the next $emailSent = ... line
            // and uncomment the one after it.
            // Keep in mind the following comment from the wp_mail() function source:
            /* If we don't have an email from the input headers default to wordpress@$sitename
            * Some hosts will block outgoing mail from this address if it doesn't exist but
            * there's no easy alternative. Defaulting to admin_email might appear to be another
            * option but some hosts may refuse to relay mail from an unknown domain. See
            * http://trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5007.
            */
            $emailSent = wp_mail(ci_setting('booking_form_email'), get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Booking form', 'ci_theme'), $mailbody);
            //$emailSent = wp_mail(ci_setting('contact_form_email'), get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Contact form', 'ci_theme'), $mailbody, 'From: "'.$clientname.'" <'.$email.'>');
        }

    }
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <main id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <article <?php post_class('entry'); ?>>
                                <?php if(!empty($errorString)): ?>
                                    <ul id="formerrors">
                                        <?php echo $errorString; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if($emailSent===true): ?>
                                    <p id="formsuccess"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php _e('Your booking request has been sent. We will contact you as soon as possible.', 'ci_theme'); ?></p>
                                <?php elseif($emailSent===false and isset($_POST['send_booking']) and $errorString==''): ?>
                                    <p id="sendfail"><?php _e('There was a problem while sending the email. Please try again later.', 'ci_theme'); ?></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>


                                <?php the_content(); ?>

                                <?php if(  !isset($_POST['send_booking'])  or  (isset($_POST['send_booking']) and !empty($errorString))  ): ?>

                                <form class="booking" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" name="ci_name" id="ci_name" placeholder="<?php _e('your name', 'ci_theme'); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($clientname); ?>">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="email" name="ci_email" id="ci_email" class="datepicker" placeholder="<?php _e('Your Email', 'ci_theme'); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($email); ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- My Edits -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <hr />
                                            <p>Please tick any of the following services if you would like to include them in your package:</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Reiki'); ?> value="Reiki"> Reiki</p>
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Private Personal Training'); ?> value="Private Personal Training"> Private Personal Training</p>
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Walking'); ?> value="Walking"> Walking</p>
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Boot Camp'); ?> value="Boot Camp"> Boot Camp</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Relaxation Massage'); ?> value="Relaxation Massage"> Relaxation Massage</p>
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Meditation Circle'); ?> value="Meditation Circle"> Meditation Circle</p>
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Colour Workshop'); ?> value="Colour Workshop"> Colour Workshop</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End My Edits -->

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <textarea name="ci_comments" id="ci_comments" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="<?php _e('Message', 'ci_theme'); ?>"></textarea>

                                            <button type="submit" name="send_booking"><?php _e('Submit', 'ci_theme'); ?></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

In the code above, I have placed the HTML markup for the checkboxes in, and it appears something similar to this on the front-end of the website:

[image]

---

However, it doesn't seem to include the checkbox information in the email that is sent off.  The email for this simply reads `Services Selected:` without the names of the services ticked:

[image]

---

My edits which can be found in the code above are:

Sanitize:

```
$services = isset($_POST['services']) ? esc_html(trim(implode(",", $_POST['services']))) : '';
```

Message to be sent:

```
$mailbody .= __("Services Selected:", 'ci_theme') . " " . $services . "\n";
```

Checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" <?php checked($services, 'Relaxation Massage'); ?> value="Relaxation Massage"> Relaxation Massage
```

How do I implement, sanitize, send and receive the results of the `checkboxes` using the `<form>` I currently have?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't store any value in your `$service` variable.

Just put this code

```
    $clientname = isset($_POST['ci_name']) ? esc_html(trim($_POST['ci_name'])) : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['ci_email']) ? esc_html(trim($_POST['ci_email'])) : '';
    $services = isset($_POST['services']) ? esc_html(trim(implode(",", $_POST['services']))) : ''; // My Edit
    $message = isset($_POST['ci_comments']) ? sanitize_text_field(stripslashes($_POST['ci_comments'])) : '';

    $errorString = '';
    $emailSent = false;

    if(isset($_POST['send_booking']))
    {
         print_r($_POST);exit; // You can see here your post variable value in array.
    }
```

Instead of

```
$services = isset($_POST['services']); // My Edit
```

Read more about the ternary operator: [http://php.net/ma...operators.comparison.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Did you try to print your `$_POST` variable? and check what is the output.

Comment: See my edit for printing your `post` variable. and let me know your output of your post variable.

Comment: Did you check your checkbox or not? because your checkbox value doesn't show in your post array.

Comment: Just removed `<?php checked($services, 'Reiki'); ?>` from your all checkbox code and see what happen.

Comment: I was tested on my local server and its working fine for me. here is my post array `Array ( [ci_name] => test [ci_email] => test@test.com [services] => Array ( [0] => Reiki [1] => Private Personal Training [2] => Walking ) [ci_comments] => test [send_booking] => )`

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you very much for sticking with me in resolving this issue.  It was for a client project and you have been an absolute gem!  Was a simple type-o and now working perfectly.